# How to pass NSMutableDictionary as a reference?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have the following set up in one of my classes where I pass an `NSMutableDictionary` as a parameter to the initializer, then I assign it to the variable `controls`.

I believe the behavior is it is copying the items of the `NSMutableDictonary` into `controls`, but I need to pass it as a reference so that the changes made are reflected in the class that is passing the dictionary to `MenuViewCell`. This always confuses the heck out of me, how would I pass a `NSMutableDictionary` as a reference?

```
MenuViewCell.h

@interface MenuViewCell : UITableViewCell
{
    NSMutableDictionary *_controls;
}
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableDictionary *controls;

MenuViewCell.m

@synthesize controls = _controls;

- (id)initWithControls:(NSMutableDictionary *)controls 
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (self)
    {
        self.controls = controls;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) setControls:(NSMutableDictionary *)controls
{
    if (_controls != controls)
    {
        _controls = [controls mutableCopy];
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to use a model instead of dictionary. Also remove `NSMutableDictionary *_controls;` line and make a `strong` property instead of `copy`. When you make a copy it doesn't keep same reference only assign will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is the use of `copy` on the property and the use of `mutableCopy` in the setter. Make the property `strong`.

You also don't need `@synthesize` or the explicit instance variable.

MenuViewCell.h

```
@interface MenuViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *controls;
```

MenuViewCell.m

```
- (id)initWithControls:(NSMutableDictionary *)controls 
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (self)
    {
        _controls = controls;
    }
    return self;
}
```

No need to override the setter.

Comment: Thanks, I had blinders for some reason, thinking you could only declare it with copy.

Comment: `copy` is very common because in many cases you do want an actual copy so changes to the original don't mess with the property. But obviously in your case you do want the changes to appear.

Comment: [self.controls setObject:control forKey: subtypeNumber]; This should still work and I should be able to see the changes in the parent class? It's not working for me for some reason, I'm able to pull the object using the key but when I try do stuff to it (like set a labels text) nothing happens.

Comment: Please post a new question with sufficient details demonstrating the issue you are having.